# Find the index position of all elements within an array with matching values from a test array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 456], [2, 3, 4, 789], [3, 4, 5, 101112], [4, 5, 6, 131415]])
```

I have an array of numbers like:

```
b = np.array([101112, 456])
```

I am looking for:

```
[2, 0]
```

How can I get the index positions in a using b?

Currently, I am using a nested loop which is highly inefficient.

I cannot get np.where to do this, at least with my limited understanding.

Comment: Are there any assumptions you can make, like the numbers being sorted? Also, are you looking through the last column of data only (e.g. a 1D array) or the full 2D matrix? your example is sorted by the last colum, and you're apparently only searching the last column. If those two assumptions hold, `searchsorted` would be your best friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your arrays you can ask:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 456], [2, 3, 4, 789], [3, 4, 5, 101112], [4, 5, 6, 131415]])
b = np.array([101112, 456])

np.isin(a, b)
```

and get:

```
array([[False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

Passing that to `any()` and then to `argwhere` will give you the one-liner:

```
np.argwhere(np.any(np.isin(a, b), axis=1)).ravel()
# array([0, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `np.where` for each value of `b`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 456], [2, 3, 4, 789], 
              [3, 4, 5, 101112], [4, 5, 6, 131415]])
b = np.array([101112, 456])
print([np.where(a == v)[0][0] for v in b])  # [2, 0]
```